# Swift: Return boolean in GCD Completion Block

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

I have a function written in Swift. I want the completion block to return a boolean. How can I go about doing this? I am using Grand Central Dispatch.

```
func myFunc() -> Bool 
{
    var success:Bool = false 

    // code here 

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 
        return success
        )}
    )}
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Standard why of dealing with this async nature is not to return value, but pass in completion handler:

```
func myFunc(completion:(success: Bool) -> ()) {
    var success:Bool = false

    // code here

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        completion(success: success)
    }
}
```

Then work with it:

```
myFunc({ (success) in
    // ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

More swifty way (Swift 5):

```
func myFunc(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
   var success = false

   // code...

   completion(success)
 }
}
```

Usage:

```
myFunc { success in
    if success {
        // code ...
    }
}
```