# Unexpected non void return value in void function while returning a value

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2

I have to call a webservice from getResonse(url) then i want to return json . I am unable how to return json in complete handler . They give me error Unexpected non void return value in void function Please help.Any help would be apperciated. Thanks in Advance

```
    func GetStation(url : String) {
        var dict = NSDictionary()
    dict = getResonse(url)
    }

        func getResonse(myUrl:NSString) ->NSDictionary
        {
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: myUrl as String)!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData, timeoutInterval: 30)
            let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
            request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
            let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
                guard data != nil else{
                    return
                }
                do {
                    if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                        print(json)
                        if (data  == nil)
                        {
                           return nil
error
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return json

error
                        }
                    }else  {
                        let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)    // No error thrown, but not NSDictionary
                        print("Error could not parse JSON: \(jsonStr)")
                    }
                } catch let parseError {
                    print(parseError)                                                          // Log the error thrown by `JSONObjectWithData`
                    let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                    print("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
                }
            }

            task.resume()
        }
```

Comment: Try to use closure block !  make func getResonse(myUrl:NSString) ->NSDictionary
 function as  func getResonse(myUrl:NSString,completionhandler:(NSDictionary) ->NSDictionary), and on getting your json inside session call complitionhandler as completionhandler(json)

and inside GetStation use completion block ! where you can get json passed from session there!

Comment: func GetStation(url : String) {
   
     var  dict = NSDictionary()
    dict = getResonse(url, completionhandler: { (dict) -> NSDictionary in
        print(dict)
    })
    }

Comment: They give error Ambigious refrence to member print

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: Return boolean in GCD Completion Block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26847344/swift-return-boolean-in-gcd-completion-block)

Answer (score 1):

This is merely a coding error (possibly due to braces being all over the place).

In you completion handler, you have 3 forced exits two of which return a value and one that doesn't.

from the "guard data ..."  -->  else { return }

in the do { ...   return nil ... or return json ... }

from the error message I gather that the later two returns are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You are inside the `dataTaskWithRequest:` of NSUrlSession which returns

```
func dataTaskWithRequest(request: NSURLRequest, completionHandler: (NSData?, NSURLResponse?, NSError?) -> Void) -> NSURLSessionDataTask
```

It returns Void inside the block. So it's showing an error.